# Why I'm getting different results in ks.boot output when applying to vectors andto xts objects?

Tags: r, function, vector, output, xts

I'm working with **ks.boot** function of **Matching** package,and I'm having different output when applying the function to a vector and to an xts objects despite the data is the same. Can anybody give a clue about it?

```
A <- as.vector(seq(1:20))
B <- as.vector(seq(from = 2, to = 40, by =2))
require(Matching)
library(xts)
dates <- seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), length = 20, by = "days")
C <- as.xts(A,dates)
D <- as.xts(B,dates)
```

The output:

```
ks.boot(B,A, alternative = "t")
$ks.boot.pvalue
[1] 0.009

$ks

    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  Tr and Co
D = 0.5, p-value = 0.01348
alternative hypothesis: two-sided


$nboots
[1] 1000

attr(,"class")
[1] "ks.boot"

ks.boot(D,C, alternative = "t")
$ks.boot.pvalue
[1] 0.672

$ks

    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  Tr and Co
D = 0.75, p-value = 2.601e-05
alternative hypothesis: two-sided


$nboots
[1] 1000

attr(,"class")
[1] "ks.boot"
Warning messages:
1: In c.xts(Tr, Co) : mismatched types: converting objects to numeric
2: In c.xts(x, y) : mismatched types: converting objects to numeric
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that xts objects (and the zoo objects they're based on) are always ordered. The `ks.boot()` function randomly samples and re-orders the observations, but that's not possible with xts objects.

For example:

```r
A <- 1:10
dates <- as.Date("2000-01-01") + A
C <- xts(A, dates)

# sample index
set.seed(21)
(i <- sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE))
## [1]  1  3  9 10  5  3  4 10  6  8

# subset xts
C[i,]
##            [,1]
## 2000-01-02    1
## 2000-01-04    3
## 2000-01-04    3
## 2000-01-05    4
## 2000-01-06    5
## 2000-01-07    6
## 2000-01-09    8
## 2000-01-10    9
## 2000-01-11   10
## 2000-01-11   10
```

Notice that the data is sampled with replacement, but the index is sampled with the observation, so the original order is preserved.

The solution to your problem is to use `coredata()` on the data you pass to `ks.boot()`.

```r
ks.boot(coredata(D), coredata(C), alternative = "t")
## $ks.boot.pvalue
## [1] 0.006
## 
## $ks
## 
##  Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
## 
## data:  Tr and Co
## D = 0.5, p-value = 0.01348
## alternative hypothesis: two-sided
## 
## 
## $nboots
## [1] 1000
## 
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "ks.boot"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for yout feedback @Joshua Ulrich, your explanation was precise.